# Julia: How to easily see the source code of a function (e.g. `quantile` function from Statistics.jl Package)

Tags: function, julia

What is an easy way to see what are the exact computations done by a function (e.g. `quantile` function from `Statistics.jl` Package). The goal being here just to understand the computations done by that particular function and not edit the entire package.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can also just use the Juno debugger to jump to the definition of any given called function with a click.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but try the @less macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look it up in the online docs:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Statistics/#Statistics.quantile

and click on the "source" link at the bottom of the function description.

Note that, like many functions in Base, the function name is used for several functions, to support multiple data types. This means that thoroughly studying the source will require looking at more than one function.

Answer (score 5):

There's [`Base.functionloc`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.functionloc-Tuple%7BAny,Any%7D), which will find you the file and line a method is defined in; but you have to specify the specific type of the method you want want to see as a tuple argument:

```
julia> functionloc(cos, (Float64,))
("/usr/local/julia-1.0.0/bin/../share/julia/base/special/trig.jl", 100)

julia> functionloc(cos)
ERROR: function has multiple methods; please specify a type signature
...
```

Comment: There's also the macro `@functionloc` which in many cases may be easier to use, as you can just use the function call syntax: `@functionloc cos(3.14)`. Whatever function call you have in your code, you can just insert `@functionloc ` before it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the `@less` macro.

> Evaluates the arguments to the function or macro call, determines their types, and calls the less function on the resulting expression.

Comment: Or the `@edit` macro, which opens the source in your favourite editor (as set by the `EDITOR` env variable).  I prefer this option as the editors (in my case Vim) are usually easier to navigate around and more featureful.